# Unable to parse Xml data to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which should get data from an XML file.  I have created a method which gets input file from a variable containing the XML content then it cycles this data and adds the of the XML (Child nodes) to a List (ex: ArrayList nameoftheList ). the list is used in the onBind method to be displayed.

my problem is the app running the recycler shows nothing!
below some code:

Edit: made suggested changes

---

### Adapter (Edit)

```
public class Adapter_recycler extends   
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> 
{


private String lista;
private ArrayList<Node> listaNodi;
private ArrayList<String> lista_errore;

public Adapter_recycler(String lista,RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.lista = lista;
    listaNodi = new ArrayList<>();


    lista_errore = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    lista_errore.add("ERRORE");

    try {
        LeggiFile();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.righe_main,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder1(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


    if(listaNodi.size() == 0)
    {
        ((ViewHolder1)viewHolder).titolo1.setText(lista_errore.get(position));
    }else{
        ((ViewHolder1)viewHolder).titolo1.setText(((Element) listaNodi.get(position)).getAttribute("name"));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   if (listaNodi.size() == 0)
    return lista_errore.size();
   else
       return  listaNodi.size();
}
```

---

### XML method (Cycles and add to the list)(Edit)

```
private void LeggiFile() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder DBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Node Players = DBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(lista)));
    Node player = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < Players.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = Players.getFirstChild();
        }
        else
            {player  = player.getNextSibling() ;}
        listaNodi.add(player);
    }

}
```

---

### Fragment (Edit)

```
public class Fragment_Chat extends Fragment {

private Adapter_recycler adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private String list = "";
Context context = getActivity();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment__chat, container,  
false);


    list = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
            "<Players>\n" +
            "<player name=\"mike\">\n" +
            "</player>\n" +
            "<player name=\"mike\">\n" +
            "</player>\n" +
            "<player name=\"mike\">\n" +
            "</player>\n" +
            "</Players>");


    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new Adapter_recycler(list,recyclerView,context);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return view;

}

}
```

Comment: The constructor for [File()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) takes in a pathname - you've handed it an XML String

Comment: So you checked the file exists, `file#exists` returns true?

Answer (score 1):

What I can see straight away is change

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return listaNodi.size();
}
```

The `Adapter_recycler`  constructor is not instantiating the Field `listaNodi`.

If that did not fix it you can put a breakpoint in `onBindViewHolder` and make sure that `listaNodi` has items.

Move

```
    try {
            LeggiFile();
..
..
```

to `Adapter_recycler` Constructor, else it will run every time a view is needed

The [DBuilder.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) can take a `String`, no need for `File`

Comment: changed but App crashes :(

Comment: @Mike-OS Check the logcat for the stacktrace and work from there.

Comment: The  LogCat show exactly on what row in the code there is a problem

Comment: Thats because `listaNodi` is not instantiating like  `private List<Node> listaNodi  = new List;` Preferably you do that in the `Adapter_recycler` constructor, or late just before using it

Comment: Move `LeggiFile()` call to `Adapter_recycler` Constructor, else it will run every time a view is needed